# beautifulsoup for google search result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to beautifulsoap and python. I want to scrape google search result by using beautifulsoap.

Expecting this:

1. Title, Link, Description of Search Results for first three result only
2. Below code I mentioned keyword in python file itself. How to make it dynamic(when run the file, it should ask me for keyword)

Below is the code I tried. However, I am stuck with the results

```
# Import the beautifulsoup
# and request libraries of python.
import requests
import bs4

# Make two strings with default google search URL
# 'https://google.com/search?q=' and
# our customized search keyword.
# Concatenate them
text= "Up Daily News"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text

# Fetch the URL data using requests.get(url),
# store it in a variable, request_result.
request_result=requests.get( url )

# Creating soup from the fetched request
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,
                        "html.parser")
#print(soup)
# soup.find.all( h3 ) to grab 
# all major headings of our search result,
heading_object=soup.find_all( 'h3' )
  
# Iterate through the object 
# and print it as a string.
for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
    print("------")
```

Comment: What do you mean by keyword? Is it the value of the text variable in your code?

Comment: You could argument parser libraries out there or maybe use sys

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to change the search keyword, which is the `text` variable in your current code. If that is the case:

You want to use the `sys` module. Here is how you should use:

```py
import sys

text = sys.argv[1]  # Note that sys.argv[0] is the file name itself.
```

Now you can run your file as:

```bash
$ python <file_name.py> <keyword>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a User-Agent.

You should write a function to acquire the query string.

Then:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

GOOGLE = 'https://www.google.com/search'

# Use this function to get the query - e.g., user input, command line argument
def get_query() -> str:
    return 'Up Daily News'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Safari/605.1.15'
}

query = get_query()

params = {
    'q': query
}

with requests.get(GOOGLE, params=params, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
    if (h3 := soup.find_all('h3')):
        for h in h3[:3]:
            print(h.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

> Expecting this:
>
> 1. Title, Link, Description of Search Results for first three result only

You can use [selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors-through-the-css-property) to target these; for example:

```py
def search_google(text, max_results=3):
    ## split then join to convert spaces to + in link
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + '+'.join(text.split())
    print('From', url, '\n---\n')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    ## loop through only the first results up to max_results
    for d in soup.select('div:has(>div>a[href] h3)')[:max_results]:
        print(d.h3.get_text(' ').strip()) ## title

        ## link
        res_link = d.select_one('a[href]:has(h3)').get('href') 
        if res_link.startswith('/url?q='):
            res_link = res_link.split('=',1)[1].split('&')[0]
        print(res_link) 

        ## description
        print(d.select_one('div:has(>a[href] h3)+div').get_text(' ').strip())

        print('\n---\n') ## separate results
```

---

> Expecting this:

> 2. Below code I mentioned keyword in python file itself. how to make it dynamic(when run the file, it should ask me for keyword)

Notice how I parametrized `text` in the function above. There are several ways to take user input in python, `sys.argv[1:]` would be one method, but I personally prefer the [`input`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/input) function, especially since you can put `search_google` in a while loop and search as many times as the user want.

```py
while (q:=input("Enter query [or q to exit]")) != 'x': search_google(q)
```

---

See these two examples using `input` and the `search_google` function from above:

| Search Query | Rendered HTML | Printed Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "UP Daily News" | [image: html1] | [image: op1] |
| "iPhone Prices" | [image: html2] | [image: op2] |